# Time ranking in matlab between cell values

Tags: matlab, datetime, rank

My matlab data has a date variable which I collect with this JavaScript code 
  `var timeStampOfOnLoad = new Date();
  Qualtrics.SurveyEngine.setEmbeddedData('timeStampOfOnLoad_FirstCondition', timeStampOfOnLoad);`

The data are stored in cell arrays like this; '**2018-01-15T17:56:15.062Z**'

I have 4 different conditions for each subject and their order was randomized. I need to check which condition has appeared first and its followings. To be more clear, I randomized the condition orders so each participant has different sequence. I want to check the order of each participants but I cannot use the `rank(A.order(:,:))`  code it gives me this error.

```
**Error in rank (line 14)**

  ** s = svd(A); **
```

Also I tried to change the cell arrays and get rid of the date part and just  by using the `strcmp` code but still I was not able to use the rank code.

Here is a part of my data;

```
     Condition 1                 Condition 2                     Condition 3                 Condition 4

'2018-01-15T17:056:15.062Z' '2018-01-15T17:46:53.107Z'  '2018-01-15T17:49:57.179Z'  '2018-01-15T17:53:09.910Z'
'2018-01-15T17:45:20.595Z'  '2018-01-15T17:48:50.694Z'  '2018-01-15T17:56:24.163Z'  '2018-01-15T17:52:32.071Z'
'2018-01-15T17:47:21.390Z'  '2018-01-15T17:54:37.342Z'  '2018-01-15T17:51:08.210Z'  '2018-01-15T17:58:20.400Z'
'2018-01-15T17:51:38.891Z'  '2018-01-15T17:48:00.568Z'  '2018-01-15T17:58:51.714Z'  '2018-01-15T17:55:04.673Z'
'2018-01-15T17:56:07.202Z'  '2018-01-15T17:48:35.489Z'  '2018-01-15T17:59:49.928Z'  '2018-01-15T17:52:38.115Z'
'2018-01-15T17:59:56.728Z'  '2018-01-15T17:48:28.216Z'  '2018-01-15T17:52:38.396Z'  '2018-01-15T17:56:19.590Z'
'2018-01-15T17:59:26.550Z'  '2018-01-15T17:48:04.734Z'  '2018-01-15T17:52:21.717Z'  '2018-01-15T17:55:58.949Z'
'2018-01-15T18:01:56.650Z'  '2018-01-15T17:54:39.215Z'  '2018-01-15T17:58:13.512Z'  '2018-01-15T17:50:48.889Z'
'2018-01-15T17:45:58.618Z'  '2018-01-15T17:50:31.997Z'  '2018-01-15T18:01:34.283Z'  '2018-01-15T17:54:56.145Z'
'2018-01-15T17:57:46.650Z'  '2018-01-15T17:53:35.369Z'  '2018-01-15T17:49:36.977Z'  '2018-01-15T18:01:44.739Z'
'2018-01-15T17:51:17.046Z'  '2018-01-15T17:55:09.768Z'  '2018-01-15T17:58:41.800Z'  '2018-01-15T18:02:24.046Z'
'2018-01-15T18:03:24.520Z'  '2018-01-15T17:59:51.090Z'  '2018-01-15T17:52:12.879Z'  '2018-01-15T17:56:04.750Z'
'2018-01-15T18:00:18.382Z'  '2018-01-15T17:53:01.234Z'  '2018-01-15T17:56:40.531Z'  '2018-01-15T18:03:54.553Z'
'2018-01-15T17:59:02.788Z'  '2018-01-15T17:55:28.473Z'  '2018-01-15T17:51:07.399Z'  '2018-01-15T18:02:43.863Z'
'2018-01-15T18:18:18.354Z'  '2018-01-15T18:06:34.464Z'  '2018-01-15T18:10:32.887Z'  '2018-01-15T18:14:29.511Z'
```

Each row gives me the information of on what date at what time participant x attended that condition.

Rows = participants
Columns= conditions' appearance date and time

Each column represents one condition (1 to 4) and I have 149 more rows. How can I rank - put them in order according to their date and time information- them? How can I check which participant started my experiment with which condition?

For example, first participant has started my experiment with **condition 2 (2018-01-15T17:46:53.107Z)** then **condition 3 (2018-01-15T17:49:57.179Z)**, then **condition 4 ( 2018-01-15T17:53:09.910Z)** and last one is **condition 1 (2018-01-15T17:056:15.062Z)**.

Therefore first participant has a 2-3-4-1 sequence.

Comment: Mh, your question is not very clear... what is it about? Sorting dates? Shuffling dates using a certain order?  Also... where are the condition orders? How is that information structured?

Comment: @TommasoBelluzzo I have already shuffled my condition orders and collected data. I need to see the order of conditons for each participant. You can see the part of my data. In that part each column (' 2018-01 .... Z' ) represents a condition's appearance date. I need to get the information of their appearance order on the screen for each participants . Sorry for my unclear question. My english is bad...

Comment: I still don't get it... can you please post the result you are expecting from that row of dates?

Comment: @TommasoBelluzzo I edited my question. Each column gives me the information of on what date at what time participant x attended that condition. I need to learn which condition was the first one for a specific participant because I need to check the effects of each condition between each other.

Comment: I got it! Answering xD

Comment: @TommasoBelluzoThanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All you have to do is to convert the date strings to serial date numbers and then perform a row-wise sorting on the result, as follows:

```
C = {
  '2018-01-15T17:56:15.062Z'  '2018-01-15T17:46:53.107Z'  '2018-01-15T17:49:57.179Z'  '2018-01-15T17:53:09.910Z';
  '2018-01-15T17:45:20.595Z'  '2018-01-15T17:48:50.694Z'  '2018-01-15T17:56:24.163Z'  '2018-01-15T17:52:32.071Z';
  '2018-01-15T17:47:21.390Z'  '2018-01-15T17:54:37.342Z'  '2018-01-15T17:51:08.210Z'  '2018-01-15T17:58:20.400Z';
  '2018-01-15T17:51:38.891Z'  '2018-01-15T17:48:00.568Z'  '2018-01-15T17:58:51.714Z'  '2018-01-15T17:55:04.673Z';
  '2018-01-15T17:56:07.202Z'  '2018-01-15T17:48:35.489Z'  '2018-01-15T17:59:49.928Z'  '2018-01-15T17:52:38.115Z';
  '2018-01-15T17:59:56.728Z'  '2018-01-15T17:48:28.216Z'  '2018-01-15T17:52:38.396Z'  '2018-01-15T17:56:19.590Z';
  '2018-01-15T17:59:26.550Z'  '2018-01-15T17:48:04.734Z'  '2018-01-15T17:52:21.717Z'  '2018-01-15T17:55:58.949Z';
  '2018-01-15T18:01:56.650Z'  '2018-01-15T17:54:39.215Z'  '2018-01-15T17:58:13.512Z'  '2018-01-15T17:50:48.889Z';
  '2018-01-15T17:45:58.618Z'  '2018-01-15T17:50:31.997Z'  '2018-01-15T18:01:34.283Z'  '2018-01-15T17:54:56.145Z';
  '2018-01-15T17:57:46.650Z'  '2018-01-15T17:53:35.369Z'  '2018-01-15T17:49:36.977Z'  '2018-01-15T18:01:44.739Z';
  '2018-01-15T17:51:17.046Z'  '2018-01-15T17:55:09.768Z'  '2018-01-15T17:58:41.800Z'  '2018-01-15T18:02:24.046Z';
  '2018-01-15T18:03:24.520Z'  '2018-01-15T17:59:51.090Z'  '2018-01-15T17:52:12.879Z'  '2018-01-15T17:56:04.750Z';
  '2018-01-15T18:00:18.382Z'  '2018-01-15T17:53:01.234Z'  '2018-01-15T17:56:40.531Z'  '2018-01-15T18:03:54.553Z';
  '2018-01-15T17:59:02.788Z'  '2018-01-15T17:55:28.473Z'  '2018-01-15T17:51:07.399Z'  '2018-01-15T18:02:43.863Z';
  '2018-01-15T18:18:18.354Z'  '2018-01-15T18:06:34.464Z'  '2018-01-15T18:10:32.887Z'  '2018-01-15T18:14:29.511Z'
};

D = cellfun(@(x)datenum(x,'yyyy-mm-ddTHH:MM:SS.FFFZ'),C);
[~,order] = sort(D,2);
```

The `order` variable will contain what you are looking for.

On a side note, I recommend you to perform a sanitization on your input dates, since the value at offset `{1,1}`:

```
 2018-01-15T17:056:15.062Z
               ^
```

contains a supplementar and unexpected value for the minutes. The `datenum` format that you specify is not flexible at all, and this will mess everything up.

Comment: That worked for the most part but for some participants it is wrong

Comment: I have already did it :) Even though I ran a sanitaziton process over my inputs the first one is still wrong, it's weird...

Comment: Must be something on javascript side.

Comment: Eventually, use a regular expression to remove any leading zero (for 3 digit occurrences) after the first ":" occurrence.